# Rails polymorphic / single-table-inheritance models, select type in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, polymorphism, single-table-inheritance

**Update:** After thinking about this some more I think this question includes both polymorphism and STI.

Let's say I have the following:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dealership
  ...
end

class Car < Vehicle
  ...
end

class Truck < Vehicle
  ...
end
```

The Car and Truck models have the same attributes but different logic in the model, so they all just use the Vehicles table.

I'd like to make a generic form that allows someone to create a new vehicle record, and to select whether it is a "Car" or "Truck". On the backend this form should then create a "Car" or "Truck" record, not a generic "Vehicle" record.

**Question:**
How do you present this option in a Rails form? Specifically, are there methods for listing the child types of an abstract base model, and/or is there a simple way to present these as (for instance) a Select element in a form?

The reason I am looking to create a form that can make a car or a truck opposed to just having two different forms for cars and trucks, is eventually I'd also like these models to be nested in a parent, "Dealership." I'd like to be able to not only create new vehicles and select "car" or "truck" as an option, but to be able to have nested forms where a user could load a "Dealership" and view/edit all the cars and trucks that belong to that dealership in a single form. I know how to set that up using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on a simple association like `Vehicle belongs_to :dealership`, but I'm not sure how to set it up for child models that inherit from Vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. Basically you are trying to build a form that accepts `has_many` association of a base class, but you want to create individual forms (add nested fields) for any of the Decorated / Concrete classes dynamically.

I solved this using the `cocoon` gem, which provided methods that dynamically add the correct fields to the form. The `_form` partial looks something like:

```
# _form.html.haml

= simple_form_for @dealership, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|

  = f.simple_fields_for :vehicles do |vehicle|
    = render 'vehicle_fields', :f => vehicle
    = link_to_add_association 'Add a Car', f, :vehicles, :wrap_object => Proc.new { |vehicle| vehicle = Car.new }
    = link_to_add_association 'Add a Truck', f, :vehicles, :wrap_object => Proc.new { |vehicle| vehicle = Truck.new }

= f.button :submit, :disable_with => 'Please wait ...', :class => "btn btn-primary", :value => 'Save'
```

And then the `_vehicle_fields`

```
# _vehicle_fields.html.haml

- if f.object.type == 'Car'
  = render 'car_fields', :f => f
- elsif f.object.type == 'Truck'
  = render 'truck_fields', :f => f
```

`car_fields` and `truck_fields` would also feature a link `link_to_remove_association` provided by `cocoon`

Take a look at `:wrap_object` documentation at https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon , or read my blog post at http://www.powpark.com/blog/programming/2014/05/07/rails_nested_forms_for_single_table_inheritance_associations

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I understand `polymorphic` as the other way around. I mean, a model can belong to more than one other model...

`Car` and `Truck` is a kind of `Vehicle`. So, lets say that `Vehicle` has `year` and `mark` attributes.

You are able to create a new `Car` or `Truck`, and having the polymorphic defined, you will create your form as usual.

```
@car = Car.find(id)
@vehicle = @car.vehicles.build(year: "1999", mark: "Beetle") 
@vehicle.save
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: You know what, I actually am looking at both polymorphism and STI, I had them a little mixed up in my head when I wrote the question originally. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: yep, I understand what you mean now. I think I found a helpful link for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047613/rails-model-inheritance-in-forms

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a simple select element on the form is the solution to your problem. What you are trying to achieve here is called `Multiple Table Inheritance` and your problem should be the way you must structure your models in order be easily reflected on the database. Because it is a long discussion I will point you to [this article](http://techspry.com/ruby_and_rails/multiple-table-inheritance-in-rails-3/) where I explain the optimal way of doing this. I hope I helped you in a way :)

PS: To answer your question, no there is no built-in mechanism of doing that kind of thing in the Rails framework.

Comment: Thanks for the article link, that looks like it addresses similar concerns. I'll take a look.